# Absolute convergence in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, contest-math

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are sequences in $(X,d)$. If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty d(a_n,b_n)$  is absolutely convergent, what do I say about the convergence of $(a_n)$ and  $(b_n)$?

Comment: why do you specify the series converges absolutely? each term is non-negative? ?

Comment: What happens if $a_n = -b_n$?

Comment: I wonder why this is tagged ([tag:contest-math]). If the problem comes from a contest, it would be nice to give a source. If this is something you needed when solving different problem, it could be useful to mention it. (So that some context for the question is given.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}d(a_n, b_n)$ is absolutely convergent (which is equivalent to convergent because $d(a_n, b_n) \geq 0$), then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} d(a_n, b_n) = 0$.

Suppose $a_n$ converges to $a$, then I claim that $b_n$ converges to $a$ as well. Note that we have

$$d(a_n, b_n) \geq |d(a_n, a) - d(b_n, a)|$$ by the reverse triangle inequality. As $n \to \infty$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|d(a_n, a) - d(b_n, a)| = 0$.

As $a$ was arbitrary, we can state that under the given conditions, $\{a_n\}$ converges if and only if $\{b_n\}$ converges, in which case, they both converge to the same limit. If they don't both converge, they both diverge, but in such a way that for any $a \in X$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|d(a_n, a) - d(b_n, a)| = 0$.

Comment: You can say more: $d(a_n,b_n)$ going to zero implies $a_n$ is Cauchy if and only if $b_n$ is Cauchy. Indeed, if $a_n$ is Cauchy, let $\varepsilon>0$. Then pick $N_1$ s.t. $n,m\ge N_1$ implies $d(a_n,a_m)<\varepsilon$ and pick $N_2$ s.t. $n\ge N_2$ implies $d(a_n,b_n)<\varepsilon$. Then for $n,m\ge\max\{N_1,N_2\}$, $d(b_n,b_m)\le d(b_n,a_n)+d(a_n,a_m)+d(a_m,b_m)<3\varepsilon$, so $b_n$ is Cauchy.

Comment: Finally. thank you alot!

Comment: and it should be noted that the convergence of the series is not used essentially, only the consequence of the convergent of the sequence of distances. I must wonder now if there are any interesting consequence to the convergence of the series.

Answer (score 3):

Take $(\Bbb R,|.|)$ the ususal metric on $\Bbb R$ and $a_n=n,b_n=n+\frac1{n^2}$ so what we can conclude?

Comment: This is a particular case, while the question is general

Answer (score 1):

Nothing, because $a_n$ could be *any* sequence and $b_n$ could equal $a_n$.

Comment: Think very well

Comment: Actually, Michael Albanese's answer is more correct. We *can* say something, as he shows.

Answer (score 1):

If the series converges, then $d(a_n,b_n)\to 0$, and so if $a_n\to L$, then since $d(b_n,L)\le d(a_n,b_n)+d(a_n,L)$, it follows that $b_n\to L$. In other words, the sequences converge and diverge together, and necessarily to the same limit. However, this only uses the convergence $d(a_n,b_n)\to 0$ and not the convergence of the series, which is much stronger. The convergence of the series implies that when $a_n$ converges, the speed at which $b_n$ converges to the common limit can't be asymptotically a lot slower than the convergence of $a_n$ (however this is hardly a precise statement, more of a heuristic that can be turned more precise). I don't see what else the convergence of the series yields.